# IntelliJ 2016.3 and protractor can't find selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor

I recently (today) updated IntelliJ to its latest release 2016.3, which promises angular2 and protractor support. Everything looks good, I can create a protractor configuration for my test file.  However, when I try to run or debug it, I get `Error message: No selenium server jar found at the specified location (/[project path]/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar)`

My test runs fine when I run it from the terminal as `protractor myTest.conf.js`

What else do I need to setup to get it to work?

MacOS 10.12.1 | IntelliJ 2016.3 | protractor 4.0.11 (installed globally and in the project.)

Comment: Have you run `webdriver-manager update`? What is in your `/[project path]/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you have run `webdriver-manager update` globally but not in your project. Try adding a task to your package.json and run that task to install selenium standalone in the project too.

```
"scripts": {
  webdriver-manager-update": "webdriver-manager update"
}
```

Then run `npm run webdriver-manager-update` in your project directory and it should install everything you need in the location you need it.

I'm not sure what the equivalent is on Mac but for me if I just run `webdriver-manager update` it will be installed under

`C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\`

but if I run the task above it will be under

`/[project path]/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager‌​/selenium/`

which is what you are looking for.

Comment: That is likely what it was. I had been running `webdriver-manager update` for the global space but not the project space.